# A coordinate free book on linear and multilinear algebra defining determinants using exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I would like to find an advanced introduction to linear and multilinear algebra that is

1)Coordinate free

2)Use tensor products and exterior algebras to define determinants

3)DOES NOT assume a previous course in linear algebra, but only assumes some mathematical maturity and perhaps a little abstract algebra like group and field definitions and basic theorems.And definitely DOES NOT assume ANYTHING about determinants, so defines them from scratch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mt_ Can you please tell what was your initial suggestion? I'm curious.

Comment: @Jxt921 Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, which does not define the determinant via exterior powers (indeed it doesn't mention the exterior algebra at all).

Answer (score 3):

S.Winitzki "Linear Algebra via Exterior Products"